# Trying to extract lines that contain string between brackets

Tags: python-3.9

The lines contain url, status code, and some other stuff. An example of the lines:

```
https://3836200.domain.com/ [404]
```

So I figured out that I can use

```
 __contains__('200')
```

But that will not work because 200 is in the subdomain but the status code is 404. I'm trying to separate lines by status code. I then figured out how to use re.search to get the strings between the brackets but it doesn't print the whole line. Any help, or reference to an article on this. Thanks. Bts I'm using python3.9

Comment: You’re on the right track. Please show your regex pattern and why you believe it’s gone wrong.  This will give us something to work with.

Comment: You could use `if "[404]" in line`

Comment: I'll try that here in a minute Tim. And S3DEV I answered that but in the wrong comment, also stackoverflow is automatically removing characters for some reason so its not right.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this format is maintained. Here is a solution for this.

```
import re
regex= "(\/ \[(\d+)\])$"
str = "https://3836200.domain.com/ [404]"

search = re.search(regex, str)
if search is not None:
    print(search.group(2))
```

Output : 404

Comment: @S3DEV sure I'm doing

    regex  = r"\[([200]+)\]"

Comment: I tried that but it's not returning anything. Also I'm trying to iterate through a file with over thousand urls and separate them based on the http status code. The first thing I tried works,  __contains__ but some of the subdomain a contains a 200,404,500 etc so that defeats the purpose.

Comment: can you share the format of the file 2-3 lines of the file will help in understanding the text pattern. If you simply run this snippet it will work successfully.

Comment: ok, it means after [404] there are some other characters as well. Just remove the $ from the regex and it will work since $ means the end of the string which is not in your case.